# SVN revert to old file structure

Tags: bash, svn

We are creating a file deploy application for a team with SVN. Here is the new scenario that want us to do,

```
User creates folder1 and checks it in
User creates folder2 and checks it in (rev2 now)
User creates folder3 and checks it in (rev3 now)
```

At this point, the user thinks he needs to go back to revision 1. so we do

```
svn co -r 1
```

the user expects to see only folder1, but not folder2 and folder3. Is this doable? We are creating the script on the Linux command line so we won't have the luxury of SVN clients to use. Only the SVN commands.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `svn` is a client. Even if it's a command line.

Comment: If it's a fresh checkout, they should only see Folder1. Are you doing a co into an existing checkout location?

Comment: Al G - This is going to an existing check out location. The repo is 15 G in size and a cron script rsync's the data elsewhere. So a fresh check out is not an option due to the huge size relatively.

Comment: You are not clear what "thinks to go back to revision 1" means. These are the options (and depending on that, the answers may differ): the user wants to revert the state of his local copy to the revision 1, to later work on it ==> use `svn diff ...` (see the comment of Ansgar Wiechers; the user wants to see the old state of the repository without working on it ==> use `svn update -r 1` instead.

Comment: mliebelt - Spot on. This was exactly what I was looking for. svn update -r <rev number> would remove any files that is NOT on the destination and restore <rev number>. I"m sorry I wasn't clear enough on my question.

Answer (score 1):

If User1 already have Working Copy and want to return to some previous revision, he have to use `update`, not `checkout`

```
>svn help up
update (up): Bring changes from the repository into the working copy.
usage: update [PATH...]

  If no revision is given, bring working copy up-to-date with HEAD rev.
  Else synchronize working copy to revision given by -r.
```